# empty list in a def function (list index out of range)

Tags: python, list, function, loops

I don't understand why my list is not used in the def function. I'm assuming it's empty because of the output but why ?

```
def check_palind(x):
    palind = []
    actual_palind = []
    palind = [int(i) for i in str(x)] 
    while palind[0] == palind[-1] and len(palind) % 2 == 0:
        print(palind,'is still a palindrome')
        print('removing',palind.pop(0))
        print('removing',palind.pop(-1))
        actual_palind.append(x)
        actual_palind = set(actual_palind)
        actual_palind = list(actual_palind)
    else:
        actual_palind = []

    return actual_palind
```

```
check_palind(900009)
```

outputs:

```
while palind[0] == palind[-1] and len(palind) % 2 == 0:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: If the list is empty, there's no `palind[0]` or `palind[-1]`.

Comment: Why do you assign an empty list to `palind[]` and then overwrite it 2 lines later with the list comprehension?

Comment: After you keep popping out elements, at some point, `palind` will become empty

Comment: Use `while len(palind) > 0 and ...`

Comment: you are removing items from palind with the pop in each loop, so after a few loops you will have an empty list. It is natural!

Comment: You're right, now that it works I have an empty list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [19]: def check_palind(x):
    ...:     palind = []
    ...:     actual_palind = []
    ...:     palind = [int(i) for i in str(x)]
    ...:     while palind and palind[0] == palind[-1] and len(palind) % 2 == 0:
    ...:         print(palind,'is still a palindrome')
    ...:         print('removing',palind.pop(0))
    ...:         print('removing',palind.pop(-1))
    ...:         actual_palind.append(x)
    ...:         actual_palind = set(actual_palind)
    ...:         actual_palind = list(actual_palind)
    ...:     else:
    ...:         actual_palind = []
    ...:
    ...:     return actual_palind
    ...:

In [20]: check_palind(900009)
[9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9] is still a palindrome
removing 9
removing 9
[0, 0, 0, 0] is still a palindrome
removing 0
removing 0
[0, 0] is still a palindrome
removing 0
removing 0
Out[20]: []
```

Comment: Thanks ! I know what I was missing now